# Do bash scripts execute in new shells or subshells?

Tags: bash, shell, scope

I am running a bash script from my bash interactive shell as:

```
./shell.sh
```

The confusion I am having is, will this script run inside a new shell instance or a subshell of my current bash instance?
I assume that all shell scripts invoked from a shell run inside a new shell therefore they aren't able to read the local shell variables of the invoking shell.
Also, if I put "echo $BASH_SUBSHELL" in my invoked script it returns me a value of "0" showing that it isn't a subshell. But according to some articles they say that a shell script when executed from a shell invokes a subshell. Please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're correct; when you run a script with `./shell.sh`, it runs in a new shell, not a subshell of the current shell.

It does run in a sub*process*, which is a shell, so it's a tempting and common mistake to say "subprocess+shell=subshell, so it must be a subshell!" But that's incorrect. The shell running the script won't inherit shell variables from the parent shell process (it'll inherit *environment* variables, i.e. `export`ed variables, but that's true of any subprocess), it won't inherit shell modes (e.g. `set -e`) or other shell state, and it won't even necessarily be running the same shell (if you're running bash and the script has a `#!/bin/zsh` shebang, it'll run in zsh). So it's logically a different shell that just happens to be running as a subprocess of the shell that launched it.